Understanding v28.0 PayToAnchor script
I am trying to understand the new PayToAnchor script, which is part of v28.0. Here is the script definition:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/src/script/script.cpp#L207-L222
As I understand, the above script would translate to following:
op_true op_pushdata4 2 4e73
Can someone please confirm that this is correct understanding? Also, what the reason for this particular script for PayToAnchor? It appears that it is not validated - interpreter.cpp#VerifyWitnessProgram, so the script could have been anything else. Is there any specific reason for using this particular script for PayToAnchor?

This Script is a 2-bytes-long version 1 witness program. It's a witness program to benefit from txid non-malleability. It's a version 1 program because for version 0 any program not 20 or 32 bytes long is invalid. It's 2 bytes long because it is the minimum length of a witness program.
The two bytes of the witness program were chosen as a vanity address. The bech32m encoding of the Script is bc1pfeessrawgf, which contains the word "fees".
The Script is slightly different from your understanding. It's OP_1 <0x4e73>, or as a byte array [0x51, 0x02, 0x4e, 0x73].
